# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException of Service class in JUnit

Tags: java, spring, exception, junit, javabeans

**TestClass.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:/WebContent/WEB-INF/application-context.xml" })
public class TestClass{

    public static FileUploadContextAware uploadContextAware;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void configure() {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "classpath*:/WebContent/WEB-INF/application-context.xml");
        uploadContextAware = new FileUploadContextAware();
        uploadContextAware.setApplicationContext(context);
        IFileUploadService fileUploadService = (IFileUploadService) FileUploadContextAware.getBean("fileUploadService");
        
    }
../Actual test code
```

**FileUploadServiceImpl.class :**

```
@Service("fileUploadService")
public class FileUploadServiceImpl implements IFileUploadService {
     ..//more code
}
```

**application-context.xml :**

```
<context:component-scan
        base-package="com.basepackage.*" />
```

I tried adding **bean** in application-context.xml as:

```
bean id="fileUploadService" name="fileUploadService" class="com.basepackage.upload.FileUploadServiceImpl" 
        />
```

But still, when I run the test, **NoSuchBeanDefinitionException** is thrown for the bean with the name **fileUploadService**. Any idea why this bean is not available in the context container?

Comment: `WebContent` isn't the class path. So it won't load the file, you would see this if you use `classpath:` instead of `classpath*:`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I guess application-context.xml file has been loaded correctly. Else, I would have got exception **Failed to load ApplicationContext**

Comment: No. Not with `classpath*:` you would get that with `classpath:`, hence the suggestion to change that.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm sorry. I think I'm not getting what you suggested. I have used `classpath*:`  Do you want me to change it to `classpath:` or it is fine?

Comment: As mentioned twice before use `classpath:` and not `classpath*:`. Those are 2 totally different things.

Comment: @M.Deinum I changed to `classpath:` in both `@ContextConfiguration` and `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` . Now FileNotFound exception is thrown for the application-context.xml

Comment: Which, as I explained, is to be expected as `WebContent` isn't the classpath. Nor is anything in `WEB-INF` except the content of `WEB-INF/classes`. Use the `file:` prefix to load it, and remove your `@BeforeEach` method as that adds nothing, you should just inject your service into your testcase. The moment you are starting to do `getBean` calls in your application, stop, take 3 steps back and reconsider as you are generally doing the wrong thing.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added `BeforeClass` just to verify that bean is loaded or not. Because, in one of the test, the Service class internally gets bean using `getBean`. Also I am not sure whether I'm missing something or not, when I use `file`: instead of `classpath*:` FileNotFoundException is thrown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221211/discussion-between-harihara-k-and-m-deinum).